# Another way to assign a function without executing it

Tags: php

Is there another way to assign or return a function without executing it? I think this is not the best solution ...

```
class Foo {
    public function getDisplayFunction() {
        return function() {
            $this->display();
        };
    }
    private function display() {
        echo 'something';
    }
}

$display = (new Foo())->getDisplayFunction();

//and execute it
$display();
```

Comment: For what are you looking for? Another way or just with less code?

Comment: I want the "getDisplayFunction" return like that: return $this->display; (works in javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it ... after trying 100 of things and 1 hour searching. Here my answer for all who looking also for the solution.

```
public function getDisplayFunction() {
    return function() {
        return $this->display();
    }
}
```

is the same as:

```
public function getDisplayFunction() {
    return [$this, 'display'];
}
```

the advantage is you don't have to pass args with this solution. That was the reason for the question.